# Tomcat 8 service - Stackoverflow error in Windows 10

Tags: spring, jdbc, java-8, windows-10, tomcat8

Running a `web-app` in `Windows 10(64 bit)`, `JVM 32 bit` and `Tomcat8.0.38` running as service as well as stand alone. The app loads fine and once it tries to load some reports(iteration), ends up getting `Stackoverflow error`.

`ERROR - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
[09 Nov 2016 14:00:16,703,http-apr-8080-exec-5,TemplateManager] ERROR - doError
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError`

But the same app runs without issues in `Win7(64 bit), jvm 32 bit and same version of Tomcat8` against same db(`SQL server`).

Tried setting `stack space` through `Tomcat Service GUI` upto `15MB` but no luck.

Is it a compatibility issue with `Win10 OS`?

Comment: `tries to load some reports(recursive calls), ends up getting Stackoverflow error` .. did you check the exit strategy, is it actually exiting from the recursion?

Comment: @random_dude Sorry. I updated it as iteration and not recursive calls. It works in Windows 7. So I don think it's the code.

Comment: Turned out it was an infinite loop in the code due to a config file missing in the environment and not related to Windows 10.

Comment: usually, its an infinite loop :)